# Issue The type 'a' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'name'. There is no implicit reference conversion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to do is validate if child entity exist to prevent remove in database.
I cannot explain the question better. please first look at my code:

my First Entity:

```
public class FoodItem<T>:IEntity<T> where T : class
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;        
    //        
    public List<T> List1 { get; set; }
}
```

my second entity

```
public class Category<T>: IEntity<T> where T : class
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    
    public List<T>? List1 { get; set; }
}
```

my IEntity Interface

```
public interface IEntity<T> where T : class
{
     int Id { get; set; }
    List<T>? List1 { get; set; }
}
```

my validation attribute class

```
public class ValidateEntityExistsAttribute<T> : IAsyncActionFilter where T : class, IEntity <T>
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    
    public ValidateEntityExistsAttribute(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {            
        var entity = _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
        var present = _context.Set<T>().Where(x => x.List1.Any());                    
    }
}
```

Now my controller action method

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]//prevent cascade delete with fooditems.count();
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateEntityExistsAttribute<Category>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCategory(int id)
    {           
        await _service.DeleteCategoryAsync(HttpContext);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

The error I am getting is in the controller action method. ValidateEntityExistsAttribute gives error saying Issue The type 'a' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'name'. There is no implicit reference conversion.

What is the correct way to implement this?